# Convergence of the sequence $\frac{(\ln{k})^s}{k^t}$ where $t, s \in \bf{R}^{+}$ and $k \in \{2, 3, ....\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to figure out under what conditions the sequence $\frac{(\ln{k})^s}{k^t}$ converges, where $s, t$ are positive real numbers. I believe that this should converge $\forall s,t > 0$, but I am not sure if this is the case. This would be based on the growth rate of a polynomial versus a power of a logarithmic function.

Similary, if
$$\frac{k^p}{(e^{k})^q} = \frac{k^p}{e^{qk}}$$
this would still hold for any $p, q > 0$, $p, q \in \bf{R}$. This is because exponentials would overpower any polynomials. Is this thought process correct in the intuition for the sequence convergence?

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty much the intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {\log(x)^s\over x^t} 
= \lim_{x \to \infty} {\log(e^x)^s\over (e^x)^t}$$

Comment: Looks like I missed my own intuition I used for comparing polynomials vs. exponentials in the question above. Thanks!